# Want to make image zoom on hover

Tags: html, css

i'm using some overlay on images and that's why i'm not getting the desired result
i'm tryin to make the image zoom on hover

```
  <div class="col-lg-3 text-center img-zoom">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h3 class="overlay-text">Menswear</h3>
    </div>
    <img src="http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-ecommerce/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/shutterstock_165191423-600x600.jpg"alt="Menswear">
  </div>
```

My CSS

```
.overlay{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
.overlay-text{
 padding-top: 150px;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

i was trying to make images zoom

```
 .img-zoom{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   transition:all 1s ease-in-out

 }
 .img-zoom:hover{
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
   -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
   -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
  }
```

but its not working i think due to overlay it zoom div instead of image. any efficient way?

Comment: Your example actually works for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: it's also working here fine but it's zooms the entire div  even i put image class in img tag

Comment: In that case, just change your selectors to use  to `.img-zoom img` which will apply the transitions to the images rather than the entire container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to alter your css selector into

```
 img{
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
 .img-zoom:hover img{
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.25);
  }
```

so that instead of adding the scale on the whole container, it only occurs on the img itself. I also included the `ease-in-out` transition on you image:

```css
.overlay{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:absolute;
 transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
.overlay-text{
 padding-top: 150px;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
i was trying to make images zoom

 .img-zoom{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   transition:all 1s ease-in-out

 }
img{
   transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
 .img-zoom:hover img{
   -webkit-transform:scale(1.25); /* Safari and Chrome */
   -moz-transform:scale(1.25); /* Firefox */
   -ms-transform:scale(1.25); /* IE 9 */
   -o-transform:scale(1.25); /* Opera */
   transform:scale(1.25);
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 text-center img-zoom">
    <div class="overlay">
      <h3 class="overlay-text">Menswear</h3>
    </div>
    <img src="http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-ecommerce/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/shutterstock_165191423-600x600.jpg"alt="Menswear">
  </div>
```

---

## My Alternative

---

To reduce markup, I would use a pseudo element for this functionality instead, as It will be much faster than using a 'real' element in your dom. I would also set the height and width (if possible) instead of using the 'scale' transform to reduce/remove the vendor prefixes which were originally required.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.container:before {
  content: "EXAMPLE";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 300px;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.container:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.container:hover img {
  height: 450px;
  /*Alternatively, you could 'scale' by setting height & width instead*/
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
</div>
```

Comment: i appreciate your work but the problem is the same your css is working but now the image is coming out of div when cursor hover's . is there any way that the container can wrap that zoom in it ?

Comment: You could use overflow hidden on the container? Or let me edit to include a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give your image an id or class and then use the `:hover` on that class instead of the whole div